# I am getting this error message when trying to do "cap production deploy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

all...I am new in Rails development. can someone tell me why I am getting this error message when trying to do "cap production deploy" ---> Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-21"] but your local platform
is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux and try again. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the go rails website and done the bundle lock also still I have the same error.  I am using the latest ruby and rails versions. Please help

Comment: My friend and I are seeing something similar to this as well. This article may help https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/understanding-the-gemfile-lock-file/#platforms

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when first deploying my rails app. I configured a DigitalOcean VM with NGINX + passenger, and got the same error when I ran `cap production deploy`.

What worked for me was to

1. run `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` on my local app
2. commit the gemfile.lock to the repo
3. then run `cap production deploy`

This seemed to do the trick for me.